# SonarLint: Remove the unnecessary Boolean literal

Tags: android, kotlin, sonarlint

I have set in a SearchView:

```
setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String) = false
    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
        filterSet.apply { 
            clear()
            addAll(searchSet.filter {
                if (newText.isEmpty()) true
                else it.name.contains(newText, true) 
            }) 
        }; return false
    }
}
```

SonarLint says `true` (before `else`) is unnecessary, why?
How else can it be done?

Comment: @risketo, i posted a code

Comment: Looks like `newText.isEmpty() || it.name.contains(newText, true)` does the trick inside the `filter`

Comment: Indeed @al3c. I wonder though if SonarLint was able to detect that or was it just a false positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have if and else in the filter, your code can be as below:

// line to change

```
 if (newText.isEmpty()) true
 else it.name.contains(newText, true)
```

// line to change

```
     setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
          override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String) = false
          override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
               searchSet.filter { newText.isEmpty() || it.name.contains(newText, true) } 
               return false
          }
      }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant, also you answered in Java?
But that's pretty close.

`searchSet.filter { newText.isEmpty() || it.name.contains(newText, true) }` is the correct answer. Please improve your answer so I can accept it. Thanks!